# Convert DICOM to PNG using dicom2.exe

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, png, dicom

I am currently trying to convert DICOM files to PNG files using a command line program named [dicom2](http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/dicom2/).

Below is the code from a .NET toy application that I wrote to test its conversion functionality. It attempts to run dicom2 from within a C# console application:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartDicom2();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void StartDicom2()
{
    string fileName = @"E:\Temp\Projects\FYP\SCE11-0353\Uploads\dicom2.exe";
    string commandLineArguments = @"-p *.dcm";

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.CreateNoWindow = false;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.FileName = fileName;
    info.Arguments = commandLineArguments;

    try
    {
        Process dicom2 = Process.Start(info);
        dicom2.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now for some reason dicom2 does not start execution at all.

Upon debugging, it was discovered that a `System.InvalidOperationException` was thrown. Not sure whether it came from dicom2 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Continued exploring about and found an isolated PNG file in the \bin folder of the project.

Apparently the program works like a charm, just that I did not look hard enough.

To make sure that dicom2 works in a specific directory, use the following line of code:

```
info.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\Temp\Projects\FYP\SCE11-0353\Uploads";
```

All converted images will appear in the specified folder. Replace the paths to whichever is convenient for you.